# Some iCloud events not showing up in iCal

Tags: icloud, calendar

A few weeks ago, I noticed that some of my events in Calender was not showing up on my mac (which is running Mountain Lion). I looked and they show up fine on icloud.com and they work fine on my iPad and iPhone. I tried removing the calender from my mac and rebooting and then readding it and the events still did not show up. I noticed that events that I would add or change since then are showing up, but there are a few that still will not show up, only ones that have been recently updated will "reappear". I have tried quitting and restarting Calender on my mac as well as removing icloud calender from my mac and readding it which did not fix the problem. I have also checked that the calenders listed were correctly trying to link with icloud and that tried to manually refresh those calenders. I also checked to make sure my software was up to date. Nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any ideas?